# What is the best time to ascend?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I have no idea when to ascend. I already have two hero souls and I am on level 90, but I haven't beaten the boss yet. Should I wait until I get to level 100 to ascend?

Answer (score 2):

As described on [this Wikia page](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Newbie_Guide:_Pre-Transcendence):

> ### When to ascend
>
> When you get to zone 130, you will want to level up all your heroes to
>   quite high levels. Press 'T' twice to toggle to the ×25 levels, and go
>   to each hero, levelling them up until the Gold requirement is
>   beyond 1000O or so. You should have about 14,000 hero levels (shown in
>   the stats in the 3rd tab.
>
> Don't worry if you have fewer, just ascend
>   anyways). This will give you 7 more Hero Souls, because, for
>   every 2,000 hero levels, you will gain 1 Hero Soul upon
>   ascending. Then you will defeat zone 130 monster and ascend, in which
>   you will use all your skills to try and defeat him.
>
> ### How to ascend
>
> To ascend, level Amenhotep to level 150 and buy his last
>   upgrade, ASCENSION. When you ascend, you will restart back at zone 1,
>   and you'll have to buy your heroes again. You'll keep your rubies,
>   your achievements, your ancients, your relics, your clans, and your
>   mercenaries.
>
> The difference is that you will have earned Hero
>   Souls, each of which gives an additive 10% bonus to your base DPS.
>   They will help make you stronger in order to progress even further
>   into the zones. Once you earn enough Hero Souls, you'll be
>   able to pass zone 160, 165, 170, and so on, until you reach zone 300.

You should consider also reading those pages, as they are very useful for beginners (I used them a lot to start the game until level 4000):

- [General Tips](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/General_Tips)
- [Heroes reguilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/5cocel/updated_hero_regilding_chart_for_clicker_heroes/)
- [Simple Idle Guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/2kk0wi/simple_idle_guide/), to get started
- [FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/wiki/faq), very useful

For more advanced players, those tools are also useful:

- [Simple Rules of Thumb Calculator](http://alexbonjour.github.io/rules-of-thumb/), to level Ancients
- [AS Builds Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m09HoNiLW-7t96gzguG9tU_HHaRrDrtMpAoAuukLB4w/htmlview?sle=true#)
- [Guides on Wikia](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Guides)